# How can I use root as my primary email address?

Tags: email, root

I have a website (say, `mydomain.com`). I currently have the email address `user@mydomain.com`, but I'd like for the email address `root@mydomain.com` to be my personal email address. Is it possible to do this safely? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it's possible... It depends entirely on what email service you are using... you could probably create an alias or a new user - `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like for the email address root@mydomain.com to be my personal email address. Is it possible to do this safely?

Yes, as a rule, it is possible to do this safely.

`root@mydomain.com` is not generally a special name in an email system like it is on some operating systems. There are some [common names](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt) defined for use with email but either *[webmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmaster)@example.com* or *[postmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmaster_(computing))@example.com* are more analogous (at least from an administration perspective).

> If so, how?

If you haven't done so, you will need to set up email services for the domain. There are a number of third-party email providers (possibly including your domain registrar) or you can set up an email server yourself.

Once email for the site is set up, in most cases, you would simply add a new user (or alias) named `root` to the list of authorized email users. If `root@example.com` were to be (possibly) prohibited by a third-party provider for some  odd reason, your choices would likely be to switch providers or run your own mail server.

Note that you can usually set email to be forwarded automatically to a specific account as well (so e.g. `user@example.com` could have its mail forwarded to `root@example.com` once created). To complete using `root` as your personal email, you would set your email client to send from `root@example.com` as normal.

---

*To be absolutely secure, you would want to use a password that was different than any other `root` logins you might have, of course.*

*This would probably include things such as actual `root` on a Unix-style system, `root@example.com` for web authentication of some sort (assuming this would even exist), any `root` user of a web-accessible application, etc.*

---

Answer (score 1):

If you are owner of `mydomain.com`, so ANY e-mail adress might be yours including `root@mydomain.com`.

How to do that depends on the settings of your e-mail server or e-mail service you use.

---

P.S. I prefer `webmaster@mydomain.com`, and I have one on my own domain.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can, I do that for more than 10 years now. But you will see that it's not always easy. Some services (mail server) have some restriction sending email to `root` username. That happened like 4-5 times only, it's quite rare but it happens and it's difficult to explain support where is the problem.

And the funny part... that happen with stackexchange ! I can't create an account with root. Other alias works fine. [Superuser refused to use my email.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XNOD.png)